# how to remove white grids in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im doing a plot with the code

```
plt.imshow(img_name, cmap = 'gray')
```

and I get white grids all over the image.
how can I remove them?

[white grids I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Xwl.png)

Comment: Set axes grid to False, plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False

Comment: You can just do `plt.grid(False)`